# How To Fix High DTU Usage on Specific Query

Tags: azure-sql-database, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have a query that runs every few seconds on a Microsoft SQL Azure Database. It is from a web job that checks if there are actions that need to be done based on rows in a specific table (its a queueing table). Based on the image attached, does anyone have any suggestion of how i could reduce the DTU usage for the query in question, it is causing the database to reach 100% CPU.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the query?

Comment: This looks like a pretty straightforward query from the screen shot--if you can provide the table definition, including any indexes, and an execution plan that would make it much easier to help, and ensure you get the right answer. You can post you execution plan on pastetheplan.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that it is a queue table, so the data distribution is probably skewed: Most of the rows have status representing completion and ideally just few rows would be candidate for process.
For the query in the image, the ItemStatus values used in the predicate are *literals* so this is the perfect use case for a filtered index:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON dbo.TaskSchedulerItem(TaskSchedulerID)
INCLUDE(DateLastUpdated, ItemStatus, TaskSchedulerItemId)
WHERE
    ItemStatus IN ('PENDING','FAILED', 'IN PROGRESS');
```

Also, periodically purging the table will help: if it really is a queue, there is no need to keep rows that have been already processed.

Comment: Only saw now that this thread had received comments. Just to help anyone else the solution for us was to delete completed rows and move them to a history table every hour. We actually found that creating indexes ended up causing deadlocks. So deleti the data and removing indexes from the table was our solution. We only ever have less than 100 rows in tge table now. Thanks all for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Not having the full table definition, I'm going to take a stab at what it might be. Based on the screenshot in your question, the table could look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TaskSchedulerItem (
    TaskSchedulerItemID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    TaskSchedulerID int,
    ItemStatus varchar(10),
    DateLastUpdated datetime2(0),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TaskSchedulerItem PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TaskSchedulerItemID)
);
```

And just for funsies, lets throw some random sample data in there:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TaskSchedulerItem (ItemStatus, TaskSchedulerID, DateLastUpdated)
SELECT TOP 10 'Pending', column_id, GETDATE()
FROM sys.columns
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 10000 'Complete', column_id, GETDATE()-1
FROM sys.columns;
```

And now we can run our query against that data:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDateTime datetime2(0)   = GETDATE(),
        @TaskSchedulerID int            = 4,
        @TaskSchedulerItemID int;

SELECT TOP 1 @TaskSchedulerItemID = TaskSchedulerItemID
FROM dbo.TaskSchedulerItem
WHERE (
    ItemStatus IN ('Pending','Failed')
    OR
    ItemStatus = 'IN PROGRESS' AND DateLastUpdated < DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, @CurrentDateTime)
)
AND TaskSchedulerID = @TaskSchedulerID
ORDER BY DateLastUpdated;

SELECT @TaskSchedulerItemID;
```

And we can see that this query does a Clustered Index *Scan*:
[image: Clustered Index Scan]

I don't know for sure that your query is doing a Clustered Index scan, but that is going to be my guess. We're only looking for one row--so ideally, we would be able to do a *seek* to that one row (or, at least fewer rows). The `OR`ed criteria makes that a little bit trickier, so having a single index that always gets us the *exact* row is a bit challenging. Instead, we can just try to get *close*.

We can create an index on `TaskSchedulerID` (we always filter on that!), and `DateLastUpdated` (we always sort on that!), and `ItemStatus` (we filter on that, but in the OR, so it's a little trickier for SQL to search on that):

```
CREATE INDEX ix_TaskSchedulerId_ItemStatus 
    ON dbo.TaskSchedulerItem(TaskSchedulerID, DateLastUpdated, ItemStatus);
```

Huzzah! It's doing a seek!

[image: Index Seek]

That should make the query pretty darned fast... but what's that little warning symbol?
[image: Seek Warning]

That's the "get close" part I was talking about. In my random sampling, the index seek was able to seek to 280 rows, then did some residual I/O to find the one row it needed that fit the critera. Based on the index I created, it is going to seek to the supplied `@TaskSchedulerID`, then start running along the `DateLastUpdated` column (remember, that's the `ORDER BY` on the query, then do "residual I/O" to figure out that `ItemStatus` criteria.

Depending on your data, that might be "good enough" to fix your performance issues. Or you might need to be a bit more clever. Since I don't know your actual schema, indexing, or data distribution, I can't hazard a better guess.

But really, you just need an index that will make your query go a lot faster, so that you use fewer DTUs.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON dbo.TaskSchedulerItem(TaskSchedulerID, DateLastUpdated)
INCLUDE(ItemStatus, TaskSchedulerItemId)
WHERE
    ItemStatus IN ('PENDING','FAILED', 'IN PROGRESS');
```

Filtered on ItemStatus and Seekable on TaskSchedulerID order by DateLastUpdated for pipelined execution.

You might still have to scan/skip a few rows

````
where ItemStatus ='IN PROGRESS' and 
DateLastUpdated >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, @CurrentDateTime)```
````